# How to update VBA program when a row or column is inserted

Tags: vba

Hi I have prepared a program using VBA in Excel in order to get properties of a selected section from a table which contains the properties of various sections.

The proper is whenever I a new row or column or even cell the target sheet my complete VBA program is becoming worthless. Can someone suggest me how the program is automatically updated when a row or column or cell is inserted or deleted.

For example in the spreadsheet itself we write a formula in one of the cells and if you insert new row above it then the formula automatically updates with new addresses of the cells included in the formula.

Hope I am clear about expressing my doubt.

Thanks.

Comment: Not very clear... From what I understand, you don't need VBA for that. A basic training on how to write formulae will suffice. Search the web for "excel Absolute relative reference"

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you want the cell reference in your program to remain the same, even if the cell moves.

To do this, you will need to use *[Named ranges](http://www.myonlinetraininghub.com/excel-2007-named-ranges-explained)*.

You will then have to change your program from using `Range("A1")` to `Range("NamedArea")`

The named ranges will be updated when the spreadsheet changes, so the reference will remain correct